# Как перекрасить кастомный шрифт

Tags: html, css, шрифты

Я скачал шрифт Cimero Pro, который выглядит вот так [image: 1]
Но мне нужен точно такой же шрифт, только полностью белый, а не разноцветный. Я добавил в css свойства для заполнения шрифта цветом, но это работает только в браузерах на базе Chromium, в мозиле и сафари шрифт так же отображается разноцветным

```css
.header__title {
  font-size: calc(72px + 88 * (100vw / 1920));
  line-height: 0.9;

  -webkit-text-fill-color: white;
  -moz-text-fill-color: white;
  -ms-text-fill-color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="header__title">Ведущие мастера по декоративной краске и штукатурке</h1>
```

Подскажите, как это исправить и сделать шрифт полностью белым во всех браузерах?

Comment: Я в ff вижу белый текст на белом фоне. Это не то что надо?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы смотрел в сторону фильтров, что-то типо (параметры подберите под свой шрифт):

```
.header__title {
  filter: brightness(30) grayscale(1);
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}
```

Comment: Да, все получилось. Поигрался немного с фильтрами, в итоге пришел к такому варианту
`filter: sepia(100%) contrast(0%) brightness(1);`